# Select an option using python from select2 and fill web form

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jquery-select2

I have this html code from select2 script:

```
<div class='round10'>
<select class='select2-authors-multiple' name='author[]' id='author' multiple style='width: 100%;'></select>
```

and this from same page:

```
<div class='round10'>
<select class='select2-narrators-muliple' name='narrator[]' id='narrator' multiple='multiple' style='width: 100%;'></select>
```

From firefox inspector i get this:

```
<input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="searchbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Select an Author" style="width: 1251.9px;">

<input class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="searchbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Select a Narrator" style="width: 1241.9px;">
```

I have made this code and it works:

```
driver.execute_script("$('.select2-search__field').val('example').trigger('change')")
```

but if fill both of forms with "example", how can i separate them?
how to ad an additional attribute to the jQuery selector to further limit the matching elements?

try to use this to identify them but it did not work:

```
# author
script = "$('.select2-search__field[id='Author']').val('example').trigger('change'))"
# generate a script via javascript
driver.execute_script(script)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change one class of input field

class="select2-search__field1"

like this

```
<input class="select2-search__field1" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" role="searchbox" aria-autocomplete="list" placeholder="Select a Narrator" style="width: 1241.9px;">
```

Comment: I wish but the site is not mine, so i cannot change the code.

Comment: if it is not yours then why do u want to sperite?

Comment: Dont understand, the idea is to fill web forms automatic, getting the data from a text file. also you want me to change the script code?