# Scroll to view in filling web form error using pyAutoGUI in Python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have this code to fill a web form:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("author").click()  # This opens the windows file selector
pyautogui.write('John')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

but if gives me an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <select id="author" class="select2-authors-multiple select2-hidden-accessible" name="author[]"> could not be scrolled into view
```

how can i resolve this? i  have tried some  code but it did not work like:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
Thread.sleep(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `pyautogui` try to instead of scroll, to navigate with the arrows `down` like this `pyautogui.press("down")`

Comment: It did not work, i should have mention i was trying to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727450/select-an-option-using-python-from-select2-and-fill-web-form

Comment: Maybe by giving us the link we can have a better view!

Comment: I think i found a way, but i think it is not the correct way:                 `pyautogui.press('tab', presses=3)
pyautogui.write('author')
time.sleep(4)
pyautogui.press('enter')´ maybe using pyautogui with javascript?

Comment: @Alexandra i don't know your ```url / link``` so i can't tell you if it's right or not. If that worked for you then don't bother yourself if it was by the correct way.

Comment: Its a private site so i cannot give the urls, but in the other question the html and the output of firefox inspector are there. Thank you for your time @bilakos